# AWS: Java application logs to AWS Cloudwatch

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jersey-2.0, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have a collection of RESTful APIs implemented using Java, Jersey2 and AWS. Currently I have configured my logs using SL4J which logs into a local file. Is there a way to send these logs to cloudwatch so that I can monitor the logs better and implement alarms in future when needed?

Answer (score 1):

You need to [install CloudWatch Log Agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/EC2NewInstanceCWL.html) on the instance and configure it to monitor your log file, by creating config file like this one in `/etc/awslogs/config/`:

```
[mylogfile.log]
datetime_format = %m/%d/%y-%H:%M:%L
file = /folder/mylogfile.log
buffer_duration = 5000
log_stream_name = {instance_id}-{hostname}-{ip_address}-mylogfile.log
initial_position = start_of_file
log_group_name = MyApplicationLogGroup
```

Here is the complete example with logging and monitoring: https://github.com/antonum/CloudWatch-IRIS